# Upload Multiple Files into Database using Spring

Tags: javascript, spring, hibernate

i've been working on a Spring Application and i am facing some problems with the Upload Files part.
In a first scenario i just have one file input type, and it worked fine but know i have put a javascript that adds more inputs and i don't really know how to handle that in the Controller.

My JSP looks like:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %> 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value="/resources/css/form-upload.css" />" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://blueimp.github.com/cdn/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/js/css_browser_selector.js"/>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
/** 
  A lot of code that make the "magic" of adding one field
*/
</script> 
</head>
<body style="background: white;">
<c:url var="subeUrl" value="/process/doUpload" />
    <form name="file1" method="POST" action="${subeUrl}" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="formulario"> 
        <div id="titulo"><p>Adjuntar archivos</p></div></br>
        <fieldset id="upload-message">
            <table>
                <tbody id="color_contacts">
                     <tr valign="top">
                        <td colspan="5" id="ancho">
                            <div class="file-wrapper">
                                <input type="file" name="filename[0]" id="filename[0]" size="9" value="" />
                                <input name="id_solicitud" type="hidden" value="${id}" />
                                <div id="hideSpan"><span class="buttones">Choose a file</span></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="for-same">
                                <div class="explorer">
                                    <button onclick="javascript:addColorControl();return false;" class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
                                    <i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </br>
            <div class="post-form"><input type="submit" value="Subir" name="submit" class="post-form" /></div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see the file names in the form are "filename[index]".

In my controller I tried this, but as you can imagine, it didn't work:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/doUpload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String doUpload(HttpServletRequest req, HttpSession session, @RequestParam("filename[]") CommonsMultipartFile[] filename, Map<String, Object> map) throws Exception{

        String cod = (String) session.getAttribute("user");

        File folder = new File("C:/wamp/www/Uploads/"+ cod + "/");
        folder.mkdirs();

        Archivo arc = new Archivo();

        int a = 0;
        if (filename[a] != null && filename[a].getSize() > 0 && a < 4) {
            for (CommonsMultipartFile aFile : filename){
                arc.setId_archivo("0");
                arc.setId_solicitud(req.getParameter("id_solicitud"));

                System.out.println("Saving file: " + saveDirectory + cod + "/" + aFile.getOriginalFilename());

                if (!aFile.getOriginalFilename().equals("")) {
                    aFile.transferTo(new File(saveDirectory + cod + "/" + aFile.getOriginalFilename()));
                }
                    if (aFile.getOriginalFilename() != ""){
                    String nombreArch = "http://localhost/Uploads/direct_download.php?file=" +cod + "/" + aFile.getOriginalFilename();
                    System.out.println(nombreArch);
                    arc.setArchivo(nombreArch); 
                }
                else {
                    arc.setArchivo(null);
                }
                    a ++;
            }
            service.agregaFile(arc);        
        }

        return "cliente/successUp";
    }
```

I hope someone can help me, I'm pretty new in spring. Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I'm answering my own question, it was really simple at the end.
I just changed the name of the inputs to `filename` so all the inputs had the same name and in my controller i changed this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/doUpload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String doUpload(HttpServletRequest req, HttpSession session, @RequestParam CommonsMultipartFile[] filename, Map<String, Object> map) throws Exception{

    String cod = (String) session.getAttribute("user");

    File folder = new File("C:/wamp/www/Uploads/"+ cod + "/");
    folder.mkdirs();

    Archivo arc = new Archivo();


    if (filename != null && filename.getSize() > 0 ) {
        for (CommonsMultipartFile aFile : filename){
            arc.setId_archivo("0");
            arc.setId_solicitud(req.getParameter("id_solicitud"));

            System.out.println("Saving file: " + saveDirectory + cod + "/" + aFile.getOriginalFilename());

            if (!aFile.getOriginalFilename().equals("")) {
                aFile.transferTo(new File(saveDirectory + cod + "/" + aFile.getOriginalFilename()));
            }
                if (aFile.getOriginalFilename() != ""){
                String nombreArch = "http://localhost/Uploads/direct_download.php?file=" +cod + "/" + aFile.getOriginalFilename();
                System.out.println(nombreArch);
                arc.setArchivo(nombreArch); 
            }
            else {
                arc.setArchivo(null);
            }
               service.agregaFile(arc); 
        }

    }
```

Just removed the `filename[]` part in the CommonsMultiPartFile @RequestParam, and put the `service.agregaFile(arc)` into the `for` .
Now all works fine! Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can inject CommonsMultipartFile on the handler method argument, try using org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile.

Also make sure you've got a CommonsMultipartResolver defined on your spring container like this:

```
<beans:bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"/>
```

And commons-fileupload jar included on your classpath (ie: as maven dependency)

Comment: Hi @gerrytan thank you for reply. As I said before, i used that method for handle one upload and it worked fine, but i will try your suggest. I already had defined the CommonsMultipartResolver in my spring container and also had the library in maven.